# How to get omniauth-facebook to load within Facebook chrome the first time you authorize

Tags: facebook, omniauth

I am trying to access my website as a Facebook canvas app. The first time I try to access my website after authorizing it (clicking the "Play Game" button) it redirects me to my website - it does not keep me within the Facebook chrome.

The second time I try to access my website, now that I don't have to authorize it anymore, it loads within the facebook chrome fine.

I have spent hours on this issue with no progress.

When I try to set:

OmniAuth.config.full_host = 'http://apps.facebook.com/xxxxxx'

It tries to hit the wrong URL after clicking the "Play Game" button. The wrong URL is:

/auth/facebook/auth/facebook

Why is it appending?